# View Other Window Environment Python not available

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

Microsoft says this about adding Python to VS Studio;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#manually-identify-an-existing-environment

Select View - Other Windows - Python Environment

I have Python 3.6 installed - I open VS Studio 2107 Community Edition, Click View - click Other - Python is not listed.  I can not seem to figure out why Python Environment is not listed.  Please assist

[Screen Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DQju.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  When I had originally installed the python extensions using the VS Installer, I did not run as administrator.  I went back and re-ran the installer as Administrator and now it functions properly.